# progressbar Action cycle in android

Tags: android

i have this code for progressbar

```
ProgressDialog.show(this, "VVV","DDD", false,true,new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                //msgDisplay("Action is cancelled");
            }
        });
```

how to bind this code to any action that i do ?

for example:

```
1. i press the button 
2. this progressbar will work
3. i run my function for doing something
4. when my function ends the progressbar will ends
```

Comment: Exactly same thing you can do with [Android-AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) easily. As you mentioned in steps.

Comment: I think now this question is of no use. You know the answer for this...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need to implement **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** in your code.

1. just include the ProgressBar inside the `onPreExecute()` method.
2. do your background task inside the `doInBackground()` method. For e.g. i run my function for doing something
3. dismiss the ProgressBar inside the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: thanks for the help, can you help me with a litle sample ? i'am new on android....

Comment: You can check [reference](http://www.technotalkative.com/loading-remote-images/) this example.